# Bypassing root detection qualify as a vulnerability?

Tags: mobile, vulnerability, detection, root, mobile-app

I am working on security testing of an android application. There is a root detection in the Android application. objection, frida etc. It is possible to bypass this with ways.

My main question is: Can this qualify as a vulnerability and is it okay to present it as a vulnerability?

Comment: I don't think it would. If you find a way to use root and bypass some control allowing you to do something unintended, that bypass could be a vulnerability.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure either, I know there is no definitive solution for root detection. am i right?

Comment: Sometimes root detection is just to raise the bar, not a definitive protection. Try to find what you could explore using root and see if you find anything interesting.

Comment: I will see, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not a vulnerability. If you own a device, you should be able to make it lie to people who don't own it. In fact, it'd be possible to make a case for the exact opposite: that if a root detection method *can't* be bypassed, it'd constitute a vulnerability in the OS or device.

Comment: (First I apologize for the late reply), So what kind of vulnerability does it register if it is not bypassed?